# Show stochastic exponential is the inverse of the stochastic logarithm

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

For an arbitrary semimartingale $Y_t$ show that $\mathcal{E}(\mathcal{L}(Y_t)) = Y_t/Y_0$.

I saw this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229040/showing-the-it%C3%B4-logarithm-is-the-inverse-of-the-dol%C3%A9ans-dade-exponential) and tried to do the same for a non necessarily continuous process but can not really see the equality of the terms involving the jumps of the process. Hence I tried to use the other characterisation of the stochastic logarithmic and the exponential functions in terms of their differentials. Namely, that $W_t = \mathcal{E}(Y_t)$ is the process that satisfies $dW_t = W_t dY_t$ and if $W_t = \mathcal{L}(Y_t)$ then it satisfies $dW_t = dY_t/Y_t$.

Denoting $X_t = \mathcal{E}(\mathcal{L}(Y_t))$, using this differential characterisation it is easy to check that:

$$\frac{dX_t}{X_t} = \frac{dY_t}{Y_t}$$

or that $\mathcal{L}(Y_t) = \mathcal{L}(X_t)$ but possibly differing at their initial point. Can we conclude from this our claim? Can anybody add some comments on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked post defines neither the [stochastic exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dol%C3%A9ans-Dade_exponential), nor the [stochastic logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_logarithm) of a semi-martingale, henceforth abbreviated by SM:

- The stochastic (aka Doleans-Dade) exponential of a SM $X_t$ is the unique strong solution to the SDE
  $$
  dY_t=Y_{t-}\,dX_t\,, \quad Y_0=1\,
  $$
  and is denoted by $Y_t={\cal E}(X_t)\,.$
- The stochastic logarithm of the SM $Y_t$ is the SM $X_t$ given by
  $$
  dX_t=\frac{dY_t}{Y_{t-}}\,,\quad X_0=0\,
  $$
  and is denoted by $X_t={\cal L}(Y_t)\,.$

The claim
$$\tag{1}
\boxed{\phantom{\Big|}\quad {\cal E}({\cal L}(Y_t))=Y_t\quad}
$$
is now trivial by plugging the definitions into each other.

In your notation
\begin{align}
X_t&={\cal E}(W_t)\,,\quad &dX_t&=X_{t-}\,dW_t\,,\;&X_0=1\,,\\[2mm]
W_t&={\cal L}(Y_t)\,,\quad &dW_t&=\frac{dY_t}{Y_{t-}}\,,\;&W_0=0\,.
\end{align}
In particular
$$
dY_t=Y_{t-}\,dW_t\,.
$$
It follows that $X_t=Y_t$ holds as soon as we require $Y_0=1$ because that
SDE has a unique strong solution. This implies again (1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is a little confusing since you are already seting $Y_t = \mathcal{E}(\mathcal{L}(Y_t))$, but did is what we have to show.

Comment: @Sarah I copied the definitions I was missing in your and the linked post from Wikipedia. My answer is self-contained and there is nothing to show. If this is not what you wanted I am awaiting an edit to your question giving other definitions of ${\cal E}$ and ${\cal L}\,.$

Comment: @Sarah Having said that: when I read OP again word for word your defintions are pretty close. Just remember where those processes start and use perhaps another notation: $Y_t={\cal L}(W_t)$ should do.

Comment: I think it would be more clear if we let $W_t = \mathcal{L}(Y_t)$ and $X_t = \mathcal{E}(W_t)$. But then it is not so obvious to me that $X_t = Y_t$ (being not carefull with the initial positions).

Comment: @Sarah Addressed that in an edit. I would strongly recommend to be careful with the initial positions.

Comment: Thank you, crystal clear now!